# I need to figure out the problem in my code as it give false results (+1)

Tags: javascript

I need help to make the right table with the same result not plus one

```
let table = document.getElementById("pixelCanvas");
let sizePicker = document.getElementById("sizePicker");

let height = document.getElementById("inputHeight").value;
let width = document.getElementById("inputWidth").value;
makeGrid(height, width);

sizePicker.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

  e.preventDefault();

  let height = document.getElementById("inputHeight").value;
  let width = document.getElementById("inputWidth").value;
  table.firstElementChild.remove();

  makeGrid(height, width);

});

function makeGrid(height, width) {

  for (let i = 0; i <= height; i++) {
    let row = table.insertRow(i);
    for (let j = 0; j <= width; j++) {
      let cell = row.insertCell(j);
      cell.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        cell.style.backgroundColor = color.value;
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `<` instead of  `<=`?

Comment: `color.value` is comming from nowhere..

Answer (score 0):

I done it only because it was fun an short to do..

```js
const in_H    = document.querySelector('#input-Height')
,     in_W    = document.querySelector('#input-Width')
,     btColor = document.querySelector('#Color-Button')
,     btDraw  = document.querySelector('#size-Picker')
,     PixTab  = document.querySelector('#pixel-Canvas')
;

function makeGrid()
{
  let hMax = in_H.valueAsNumber
  ,   wMax = in_W.valueAsNumber
  ;
  PixTab.innerHTML = null
  for (let h = 0; h < hMax; h++)
  {
    let row = PixTab.insertRow(h)
    for (let w = 0; w < wMax; w++)
      { row.insertCell(w) }
  }
}
makeGrid()  // for init
btDraw.onclick = makeGrid

PixTab.onclick=e=>{
  if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'td') return
  e.target.style.backgroundColor = btColor.value
}
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; margin: 1em }
td { border: 1px solid grey; width: 1em; height: 1em; }
```

```html
<p>
    height: <input type="number" min="5" max="20" value="5" id="input-Height">
    width:  <input type="number" min="5" max="20" value="5" id="input-Width" >  
</p>
<p>
    <input  id="Color-Button" type="color" >
    <button id="size-Picker" >draw new rect</button>
</p>
<table id="pixel-Canvas"></table>
```